# How to lag over month and over year at the same time?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to find percentage change per each month per company.
Table

```
    Year    Mon         company_id    Revenue   
    2018    2018-06-01      42          2000         
    2018    2018-07-01      42          3000
    2019    2019-06-01      42          4000         
    2019    2019-07-01      42          9000
```

I attempted this and failed.

`select *, lag(Revenue) over(partition by company_id  order by Year) from table`

working to get the bellow result ( the table has multiple company_ids)

```
    Year    Mon         company_id     Revenue   percentage change 
    2018    2018-06-01      42          2000         
    2018    2018-07-01      42          3000
    2019    2019-06-01      42          4000         100 
    2019    2019-07-01      42          9000         200
```

Comment: Can you explain how it is that June 2018 occurred in 1999?  I would have thought June 2018 occurred in 2018,.

Comment: sorry sir, lost in translation, I edited this a couple of mins ago for the sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woof!

You need to tickle out the month so that you can partition by it:

```
WITH subq AS (
   SELECT year, mon, company_id, revenue,
          lag(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id, extract(month FROM mon)
                             ORDER BY year) AS prev_revenue
   FROM "table"
)
SELECT year, mon, company_id, revenue,
       (revenue - prev_revenue) * 100.0 / prev_revenue AS percent_change
FROM subq;
```

This assumes that the `date` stored in `mon` only serves to identify the month, and that the "year" part of it (which is different from `year`) is irrelevant.

Comment: what I want to say: "Hey @laurenz, I just want to say thank you for your help! you answer saved me a lot of time and frustration, and I really appreciate you taking time to answer this question! you have a great rest of the day! " 
what I say: Thank you !!

Comment: Elegant solution, but it selects the last row with the *same month*, not necessary the of *the last year* if data incomplete. Can you comment the difference between `lag` and `max` from the other answer?

Comment: I didn't look at the other answer. The obvious question is why months are stored as `date`, and why the year part of the month is different from `year`. I assumed that everything except the "month" part of those dates is irrelevant. If that assumption is wrong, so is my answer.

Comment: My point was an other @LaurenzAlbe, the case there are data for say `2017-06` and `2019-06`, i.e. `2018-06` is missing. The `LAG` used finds the last *available* data, not the *one year old* data. Thefore I used the ` range between '1 year' PRECEDING` but with some unexpected result for `lag` (`max` worked fine).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber That's true. But perhaps there are no missing data (OP didn't give any details). Also, it's not quite clear what would be the desired behavior if there are missing data.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) to get exact the row with offset one year in the past.

```
 max(revenue) over (partition by company_id  order by mon range between '1 year' PRECEDING  and '1 year' PRECEDING ) revenue_lag
```

This will work even if you have a *missing data* for some year (you will not match a two or more years old revenue).

Unfortunately this does not work for me in `14.6` with `LAG` (not sure if per design), so I'm using `MAX`.

**Example**

```
with tab as (
select * from (values 
(2018,date'2018-06-01', 42, 2000),
(2018,date'2018-07-01', 42, 3000),
(2018,date'2018-07-15', 42, 3020),
(2019,date'2019-06-01', 42, 4000),
(2019,date'2019-07-01', 42, 9000)
) tab(year, mon, company_id, revenue)
)
select tab.*,
max(revenue) over (partition by company_id  order by mon range between '1 year' PRECEDING  and '1 year' PRECEDING ) revenue_lag,
lag(revenue) over (partition by company_id  order by mon range between '1 year' PRECEDING  and '1 year' PRECEDING ) lag
from tab
;

year|mon       |company_id|revenue|revenue_lag|lag |
----+----------+----------+-------+-----------+----+
2018|2018-06-01|        42|   2000|           |    |
2018|2018-07-01|        42|   3000|           |2000|
2018|2018-07-15|        42|   3020|           |3000|
2019|2019-06-01|        42|   4000|       2000|3020|
2019|2019-07-01|        42|   9000|       3000|4000|
```